# Sum of interior angles of a polygon

Tags: geometry

I need help with this exercise.

"Using the figure below, determine the measure of the interior angle at vertex A."

[image]

Choose one:

a. $60^\circ$
b. $150^\circ$
c. $300^\circ$
d. $150^\circ$

I would like to know if what I did is right.

Since polygon has a 7 sides the sum of the interior angles is $(7-2)180^\circ=900^\circ$.

Then,

$$2x+2x+6x+5x+5x+5x+5x=900$$
$$30x=900$$
$$x=30$$

Then,

Angle with vertex $A$ has a measure $5x=5(30)=150^\circ$.

Is this ok?

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Yes this is correct. The interior angles of a polygon with 7 sides is always 900°. And the calculation is correct as well. The answer is d).

Comment: Someone submitted an edit to change $60\degree$ to $60°.$ Rather than approve that edit as-is, I clicked on "improve edit" and changed it to $60^\circ,$ coded as `60^\circ`. Are there other opinions as to which looks better (the two options being $60°$ and $60^\circ$)?

Comment: Perhaps worthy of note is that the angle given as $6x$ has measure $180^\circ$ so is actually a straight line and the polygon has only 6 sides. Regardless, the answer is the same. Also, are answer options b. and d. both meant to be $150^\circ$?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\d}{^\circ}$Imagine driving a car counterclockwise around this circuit. At angle $A,$ you turn $180\d-5x$ to the right.

Add up all your right turns as you go around, counting a turn to the left as a negative number of degrees to the right. To complete one full circuit, you turn $360\d$ to the right. So
\begin{align}
360\d & = 180\d-5x \\
& {} + 180\d-5x \\
& {} + 180\d-5x \\
& {} + 180\d-2x \\
& {} + 180\d-6x \\
& {} + 180\d-2x \\
& {} + 180\d - 5x 
\end{align}
Solve that for $x.$

Comment: This is equivalent to solving $2x+2x+6x+5x+5x+5x+5x=900°$ and is thus the same answer OP already proposed.

Comment: @Saha : But it also explains a reason why that should be the sum: the sum of the turns should be $360^\circ. \qquad$

Comment: Ok, fair enough.